# Checking the existence of a css selector through if conditions

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm writing a code that automates the logging in and testing process of a website. It takes the login credentials from a variable and checks if the login is successful or not. To do the same, I'm trying to locate a Log Out Icon tag and print the results accordingly. Below is my code:

```
if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.signOut.logout-icon'):
    print "Sign In Succesful"
elif browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.msg.ux-error '):
    print "Sign In Error"
else:
    print "Other issues"
```

However, the above code gives me the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".signOut.logout-icon"}
```

I know that Logout icon can't always be located, which is why I gave more else conditions. Why is it not going to the next conditions in the absence of the css selector and instead throwing me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **is_dispalyed()** to check whenther element is present or not.

try below code :-

```
  if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.signOut.logout-icon').is_displayed()
        print "Sign In Succesful"
    elif browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.msg.ux-error ').is_displayed():
        print "Sign In Error"
    else:
        print "Other issues"
```

or try below code :

```
try:
    if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.signOut.logout-icon').is_displayed():
          print "Sign In Succesful"

except NoSuchElementException::
    if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.msg.ux-error ').is_displayed():
            print "Sign In Error"
except :
print:"other issue"
```

Comment: The "Other Issues" part always gets executed this way, no? I want it to try first two conditions and if it fails both, "Other Issues" is the default value. The second code is printing both "Sign In Error" and "Other Issue"

Comment: Thanks. The updated one works. I do wonder what was wrong with the if construct though. Please let me know what's wrong with that one, if you know it.

Comment: if we use only if statement with .is_displayed() it will return either boolean value or exception . So if we don't handel that exception it will break our code. So i have used exception handeling then try to locate another element with same logic